# Setup a loopback address in Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: network-manager

I have a development setup with docker where I need to have a loopback address set up on my laptop.  Currently, I am able to do that by running the following:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.254.254.254/24 brd + dev wlp2s0 label wlp2s0:1
```

The issue is that when I come back to my system after leaving it for a while, I need to rerun this command in order to get my dev environment working again.  I'd like to make this persistent in order to not have to run this command all the time.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 Minimal Install.

I have tried adding the following line to `/etc/network/interfaces` without any success:

```
up sudo ip addr add 10.254.254.254/24 brd + dev wlp2s0 label wlp2s0:1
```

My `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` contains the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system                           
network:                                                                         
   version: 2                                                                     
   renderer: NetworkManager
```

Therefore I assume that it is network manager (i.e. `/etc/network/interfaces`) that I need to configure but can't seem to figure out what I need to put in there.

Answer (score 2):

I have settled on the following solution, should it help someone out there in the future.

I have edited my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` to the following in order to get a loopback address.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    lo:
      renderer: networkd
      match:
        name: lo
      addresses:
        - 10.254.254.254/24
```

It essentially keeps the NetworkManager as the renderer for all other interfaces but loopback, and sets the address that I wanted as a loopback address.  The address is no longer on my wireless interface, but I think this is actually preferable.

Comment: This seems to be the only thing that works in modern Ubuntu as everything else, `ip addr`, `iptables` etc. don't persist after reboot.